# How to use dynamic routing in ReactJS with a colon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I want to change my routing according to product id, which is dynamic.

I found this solution of variables using a colon.

```
path: "/:product_id" component: ProductDetail
```

How can I use `product_id` in my components.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [explained in the docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params), you can access data from the `params` object on the [`match`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match) prop.

In your case, it would be: `match.params.product_id`. For example:

```
function ProductDetail({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>PID: {match.params.product_id}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```